# MVC 5, other languages for layout are working but for views and partial views not

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have crated a new area on mvc 5 and resource files and other languages are working for layout but content in view or in partial inside this area I created remains in English even if i change language on language dropdow.

What can be the wrong?

Comment: Can you please share some code of what you did?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!